# Setting up pow.cx to use Apache for PHP apps

Tags: apache, virtualhost, pow

I've set up Pow and Apache the way they suggest in [this](https://github.com/37signals/pow/wiki/Running-Pow-with-Apache) tutorial. My `httpd-vhosts.conf` contains the following entry.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Users/michael/Dropbox/Development/test
    ServerName test.dev

    <Directory "/Users/michael/Dropbox/Development/test">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm still getting a 403 Forbidden when I got to http://test.dev/.

Error log says:

```
[Wed Nov 21 19:24:21 2012] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: /Users/michael/Dropbox/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
[Wed Nov 21 19:24:43 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
```

Has anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the permissions. It finally worked when I chmod'd the full path to the directory I was working in to 755.

~/, ~/Dropbox, ~/Development...etc.

I'll bet there's a nicer way to do this, but it's working. So, there you go.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have nothing to do with Pow. Apache doesn't have the necessary permissions to work within `/Users/michael/Dropbox/Development/test`.

Please check the permissions of this directory, I think they should be 755. Check them with:

```
cd /Users/michael/Dropbox/Development/  
ls -l
```

And copy paste the line of the `test` directory.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. "drwxr-xr-x   3 michael  staff   102 Nov 20 17:44 test" is what I get.